# Getting Maya Custom Hotkeys List

Tags: maya, hotkeys, mel

I want to share my Maya hotkeys for custom commands along team. Of course, I can use "hotkeySet" command with -export, -import. But in this case, it override all of them with the file. It means that

> If I change "save file" to "Ctrl + Alt + S" (sure, it's so weird). I
>   don't want to make my team members to use that weird hotkey.

How can I get the list of my custom hotkeys? If I can know that, I can export and import them selectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share your Maya's custom hotkeys along your colleagues, you'll need to copy `userHotkeys.mel` (or `userHotkeys_Maya_Default_Duplicate.mel`) and `userNamedCommands.mel` files from your comp to the destination team's comp. One more file named `userRunTimeCommands.mel` is typically empty one.

These files are located in the following directories on different OS:

`macOS` – `~/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/2016.5/prefs/hotkeys`

`Linux` – `~<username>/maya/2016.5-x64/prefs`

`Windows` – `\Users\<username>\Documents\maya\2016.5-x64\en_US\prefs`

If you open Maya's Script Editor and check `Echo all Commands` option 
on and then save a custom shortcut in Hotkey Editor, you'll notice that Maya saves/updates these three files when you create or edit your hotkey.

For instance, I've created hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> for toggling a grid in Viewport.

```
hotkey -keyShortcut "g" -alt -name ("ToggleGridNameCommand");
```

This is what I can see in Script Editor:

[image]

After that you can share saved `userHotkeys.mel` and `userNamedCommands.mel` files along your team. Also you can edit these ASCII files in any Text Editor.